# How can I find the difference between a cross join query and another query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(e.ssn), c.class     
FROM enrollment e
CROSS JOIN 
class c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM enrollment e2
);
```

So, I'm trying to first get a table with the ssn and class attributes in it and then I want to only keep the rows that are not in the enrollment table, I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Seems like an anti-join will produce the result you want but it's difficult to tell from the explanation.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you posted sample data from both tables, the actual results and what you expected them to be instead (all as text, not screen shots)

Answer (score 0):

To get the lines from table1 where there is no matching value in table2 we can write:

```
Select table1.*
From table1
Left join table2
On table1.joiningColumn
  = Tables.joiningColumn
Where table2.joiningColumn is null;
```

The left join means that we get all rows from table1 whether they match or not and the where clause rejects the rows which are matched.